# How to get the location of the post in GraphApi?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I wonder how do I get the location of the post from Graph API ?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[SOME_ID_THAT_I_HAVE_ACCESS_ON]/posts?limit=10&offset=0&access_token=[TOKEN];
```

This retrieves all posts by the user but the retrieved data doesn't have the location/place field.

Is it possible to get the location of all posts (if specified by the user)?

**Notice: I tested the above on a test acocunt where I posted all posts and shares with location.**

Comment: Was there any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need `read_stream` permission for the `place` field.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I have it, but still no places/locations